# Renew Certs for argoCD - Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, cacerts

Hi I am trying to renew argoCD certificates which expired on May 6th, I followed all the steps from the documentation (attached to this).

"To create this secret manually from an existing key pair, you can use kubectl:

```
kubectl create -n argocd secret tls argocd-server-tls \
  --cert=/path/to/cert.pem \
  --key=/path/to/key.pem
```

**Argo CD will pick up changes to the argocd-server-tls secret automatically** and will not require restart of the pods to use a renewed certificate."

and the ArgoCD is still not showing the latest renewal date. I tried Manually restarting the pods, but still showing the previous renewal date.